# picking the right record out of the view script

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I´m just trying around to become familiar with Zend Framework 2. I try some different possibilities each component. Now I´m testing around with viewscripts to get the details better. The trouble is, I don´t understand how to pick the right record to delete. I get always the first one.

I have a viewscript in html like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Tag</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Zeit</th>
        <th>Thema</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $lodge = new Application_Model_DbTable_Arbeitskalender();
        $i=1;
        foreach($this->aktermine as $termin) :      
    ?>    
    <tr>
        <td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->nr);?></td>
        <td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->day($termin->datum);?></td>
        <td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->date($termin->datum);?></td>
        <td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->zeit);?></td>
        <td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->thema);?></td>
        <td  class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'aktermine', 'action'=>'edit', 'kopfnr'=>$termin->kopfnr));?>">
            <img src="Images/Icons/edit.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="Termin editieren" /></a>
        </td>
        <td  class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'aktermine', 'action'=>'delete', 'kopfnr'=>$termin->kopfnr));?>">
            <img src="Images/Icons/minus.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="Termin entfernen"/></a>
        </td>
        <td  class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'aktermine', 'action'=>'add', 'kopfnr'=>$termin->kopfnr));?>">
            <img src="Images/Icons/plus.jpg" width="16" height="16" title="neuer Termin"/></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $i=$i+1;
        endforeach; 
    ?>
```

If I use my delete action I get always the first record. How can I select the right record, how does this work? I have the suggestion, that it is because of the icons. In another viewscript I have links instead and there it works. So how to work with icons? Here ist my delete action also:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');
        if ($del == 'Yes') {
            $nr = $this->getRequest()->getPost('nr');
            $aktermine = new Application_Model_DbTable_Aktermine();
            $aktermine->deleteTermine($nr);
        }
        $urlOptions = array('controller'=>'aktermine', 'action'=>'index');          
        //redirector = Seitenaufruf controller, action
        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute($urlOptions);
    } else {
        $nr = $this->_getParam('kopfnr', 0);
        $aktermine = new Application_Model_DbTable_Aktermine();
        $this->view->aktermine = $aktermine->getTermine($nr);
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you are just starting out with ZF2 your first project should be the [tutorial application](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/overview.html#the-tutorial-application). It [specifically answers your question in great detail](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html#deleting-an-album).

Comment: thanks I did this already, but now I'm trying different possibilities for the same result

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I had an (copy/paste) error in my get function, I used the foreign key instead of the primary key.